# Добавить Linux в boot menu BIOS’а

Tags: linux, windows, bios

решил на себе опробовать семейство Linux, начал, естественно, с Ubuntu.
После своего первого знакомства с данной ОС столкнулся с проблемой мертвого экрана.

Страдал я от неё не мало, пытался как гуглить решение, так и заменить на другой дистрибутив, который устанавливал и удалял по несколько раз. В итоге забил я на этот ваш Linux.

И тут, спустя долгие пол года вновь решил испытать удачу, и, о чудо, все работает отлично.

Но вот моя перфекционическая жилка не даёт мне покоя, тк для смены ОС (на 1ом диске стоит Win10, на 2ом диске - Ubuntu) приходится в BIOS’e ставить нужный носитель в качестве загрузочного. А хочется выбирать его(носитель) в boot menu, который доступен по нажатию клавиши f12 во время загрузки пк.

По данной теме нагуглил себе неразбериху, поэтому решился попросить помощи.

Также, в моем boot menu присутствует пункт ”Ubuntu”, который остался от прошлополугодних экспериментов, и который при его выборе загружает носитель, выбранный в качестве загрузочного, хотелось бы от него избавится

Стоит у меня Dual BIOS, версии f20

Помогите, пожалуйста, кто чем может [image: Мое boot menu, о котором я говорил. Сейчас выбран носитель, на котором стоит Ubuntu]

Comment: Почему *"естественно, с Ubuntu"*? Используйте `systemd-boot`, если уже стоит `systemd`

Comment: @dIm0n, не совсем понял о чем вы говорите

Comment: У вас UEFI или нет?

Comment: @dlm0n, стоит UEFI

Comment: @AlexandrKorzh, после дефольной установки Линукса, там должно всё переключаться при старте с помощью GRUB.

Comment: @AlexandrKorzh ну так используйте https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-boot

Answer (score 2):

> приходится в BIOS’e ставить нужный носитель в качестве загрузочного.

Если на компе установлено две (или более) ОС, то выбирать из них какую-то одну для очередной загрузки как то **необходимо**. Так ?

Существует всего два механизма сделать это:

1. Две операционки стоят на двух разных винтах и Вы сами в BIOS выбираете - что именно загружать. Ни одна из опреационок ничего не знает о существовании другой.
2. Одна из операционок "знает" про другие. Загрузка всегда идёт с диска именно этой операционки, а уж её загрузчик позволяет Вам в меню выбрать конкретную загружаемую ОС.

Загрузчик *ntloader* для *windows* не умеет так. Загрузчик *grub* для *Linux* справляется с этой задачей легко. Поэтому, рекомендую Вам действовать так:

1. На один из винтов устанавливаете виндовоз. Она устанавливается обязательно **первой** т.к. кроме себя любимой не видит ничего и при установке второй может снести нафиг всё, что ей не понравится.
2. Установка производится так, что бы один из дисков (или один из разделов диска) остался **не** занят виндовозом.
3. Вставляете установочный CD или флэшку Ubuntu и устанавливаете Linux на **свободный** диск. Для этого Вам придётся указать его в явном виде, когда установщик спросит, согласны ли вы с установкой дисков по умолчанию. Вам нужно сказать, что у Вас у самого есть голова и указать именно свободный диск.
4. Когда вы будете корректировать таблицу установочных разделов, очень важно указать, что загрузка будет идти именно с *Linux* диска. Это приведёт к тому, что инсталлятор установит туда Grub, BIOS будет грузить Grub, а он даст Вам возможность выбора загружаемой ОС.
5. Выполнить обычную установку.
6. В BIOS **один раз** указать загрузку с Linux диска.

В результате Вы получите т.н. мультизагрузочную систему. Настраивая Grub легко задать какая именно система будет загружаться по умолчанию - Linux или Windows.

У него вообще очень много возможностей. Вплоть до того, что фоном загрузки можете поставить свою картинку. :-)  Но, главное: Grub обеспечивает загрузку множества разных ОС, с расположенных на HDD / SDD носителях на этом компе. Кувыркайтесь, как пожелаете! Можете установить Windows 95, Ubuntu 20.04, Windows-10 и LFS на одном компе :-) Grub с этим разберётся.

PS: Если Вы хотите установить Linux на котором уже стоит виндовоз и она захватила **все** разделы/диски на этом компе, то инсталлятор линуха предложит Вам "поджать" один из виндовозных разделов. Это не очень красивый вариант, но для первого раза - сгодится. Просто проверьте дисковое пространство разделов, которое Вам предложит инсталлятор...

Comment: Если уже стоит `systemd`, то лучше использовать `systemd-boot`, чтобы не плодить сущности без необходимости, как минимум

Answer (score 0):

EasyBCD - это мощный инструмент для модификации загрузчика, который имеет широкий спектр приложений и применений. Он может выполнять множество задач, варьирующихся по сложности и применению, от самых простых до продвинутых и настраиваемых функций.

Пожалуйста, используйте EasyBCD с осторожностью.

EasyBCD бесплатен для личного использования.